# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.3. error found in build.gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, build-script

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.3.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.3.3/gradle-7.3.3.pom
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.3.3/gradle-7.3.3.pom
Required by:
    project:
```

Answer (score 145):

Changes the Gradle JDK to jdk-11 helped me:

[image]

Comment: I changed to Android Studio java home.

Answer (score 81):

The "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$version" is what we called Android Gradle Plugin(AGP), its latest stable version is **7.0.4** (until 1st Jan 2022), you can check all available versions [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google).

The **7.3.3** is for the Gradle platform itself, you can check all available versions [here](https://gradle.org/releases/).

For their relationship, please check [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle).

Comment: I ran into this a couple of years ago and nothing worked, it was easier to manually generate the aab file from my eclipse and left it there, fast forward to now same issue still none of the hints here work ...not cool

Answer (score 22):

change gradle jdk version worked for me

- go to File, Settings, Build, Execution, Deployment
- build tools, gradle
- Change Gradle JDK from the dropdown. I use `Android Studio java home`

Comment: This didn't solve the issue for me?

Comment: @khalidalsaleh Go to File -> Invalidate Caches -> Check all optionals -> Click Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 14):

Follow the below steps:

1. Go to `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build tools > Gradle`
2. Then change `Gradle JDK` from the dropdown and select `Android Studio java home`
3. Click Apply and/or OK

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Go to File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deploment -> Build Tools -> Gradle

Then, choose Gradle JDk to 11 Version...

Click Apply -> Okay

Then, Click Try Again on the top to run Gradle Again or you can Rebuild your project.

Answer (score 3):

go to File, Settings, Build, Execution, Deployment
build tools, gradle
Change Gradle JDK from the dropdown. I use Android Studio java home

Answer (score 2):

I tried gradle 7.4.2 and everything is working fine now

`https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip`

Answer (score 2):

For me the Problem was that the project was building fine and producing the apk. But when I run on the command line commands like:

```bash
./gradlew clean
```

I was getting the same error as you.

After many attempt, including even verifying multiple time that I got the right "Gradle JDK (11)" on Android studio, I figured out that maybe the command line fail since it doesn't use the same jdk as the one used by Android studio when I click the "Build Project" button.

I run the command "java -version" on the command line and I found out it was using "openjdk version "1.8.0_362" (Java 1.8) and that I also never set the environment variable $JAVA_HOME in my computer.

So I figured that by installing the Java 11 in my computer "beside the one used by Android studio" and setting as my default would solve the problem.

So I proceeded as such :

```bash
sudo yum reinstall java-11-openjdk
```

After that you can either choose to set the environment variable $JAVA_HOME as pointing to this newly installed JDK 11 or run the command :

```bash
sudo update-alternatives --config 'java'
```

and choose the newly installed JDK 11 from the menu to be your default.

By doing this, my "./gradlew .." command from the terminal works again.

Finally,

The command are given for a Fedora or RHEL based distros, but should easily translate to other distros.

For windows, you can just check that the $JAVA_HOME environment variable is pointing tot he right location.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add google in the repositories block
in app level build.gradle file:
Because android gradle plugin resides on google repository

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
     google()
     // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: This didn't help me in my case (what are the `..` after `google()`?). What helped was an explicit maven URL reference, and not in `allprojects` section but rather in the `buildscript` section. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74756828/2597758

Answer (score 0):

just check if your internet/wifi is restricting to downloading Gradle.
Because for me my office wifi was restricting so switch to my personal mobile data and re-run the project it should automatically download the appropriate gradle version because it worked for me

I got this error after upgrading the Flutter version
`to 3.10.0 from 3.7.7`
since I was using Android studio Electric Ele so above solution was not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check your build.gradle, make sure repositories has those two items.

```
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```