# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I installed Android Studio for the first time (2021.3.1.17) and proceeded to import an Eclipse/ADT project of mine.

The import of the project itself seems to have gone well, but I received the following error:

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.3.1/gradle-7.3.1.pom
```

I added to the project's `build.gradle` the following:

```
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
```

so that it now has:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

But I am still getting this error.

What am I missing? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved by moving maven clause from `allprojects` to `buildscript` such that the entire build.gradle is now:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Also note that the `compile` configuration has been deprecated since Gradle 4.10 (Aug 27, 2018), and was finally removed in Gradle 7.0 (Apr 9, 2021), [replaced by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796404/could-not-find-method-compile-for-arguments-gradle#comment131940678_66910991) `implementation`.