# android - upgrading build gradle version error

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to upgrade my build gradle version but I ran into errors . this is my gradle :

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
    }
```

this is gradle wrapper :
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip

it has downloaded gradle-7.4.2-all.zip but it doesn't download gradle:7.4.2 ... this is the error

```
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
Searched in the following locations:
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.pom
  - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.pom
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.pom
  - https://jitpack.io/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.4.2/gradle-7.4.2.pom
```

what shall I do ?

Comment: This can happen if your network connection was defect at the time when gradle tried to download android gradle plugin, because the first link to dl.google.com works. If your network connection has no data plan (flat) you can delete gradle cache `~/.gradle/caches/` and redownload everything.

Answer (score 1):

Best and simple working solution is go to file option in android studio then click settings then under Build, Execution, Deployment option click on gradle then under gradle properties click on project name then under gradle sub category in gradle JDK choose Embedded JDK, and then click on apply and sync your gradle files then it will surely work.

OR

visit this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76088614/19674027