How to solve this error in flutter build apk?
when I run flutter buil apk this error is appear

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.


Could not find builder-test-api-7.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-test-api:7.3.0).
Searched in the following locations:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-test-api/7.3.0/builder-test-api-7.3.0.jar
Could not find ddmlib-30.3.0.jar (com.android.tools.ddms:ddmlib:30.3.0).
Searched in the following locations:

it usually run successfully but this error apear today
in some previos projects still work but other no

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76088614/5197712 Try this
